# VC6 is remembering a dll location that an activeX controller uses and I cant find where to change it

Tags: c++, dll, activex, visual-c++-6

I moved a project from one directory to another having just added an ActiveX Controller that I made (which uses a dll I made). I have never told VC6 where to find the dll, all i did was add the ActiveX controller, when I deploy the project it works fine but I can't remote debug, when i do it says file not found and states the old location for the dll (within the project, I put the dll in the root of the project directory and it worked so i didn't question it) I've done a text search on all the fiels in the project checked the dll the activeX code the registry and the settings for the VC6 project and nowhere can i find a reference to this old file path, any ideas out there?

Comment: Visual Studio 6, are you serious?

Comment: it's not my company who am I to judge :)

Comment: The location is stored in the registry, put there by Regsvr32.exe.  Done automatically when you build the control.  That needs to happen on the remote machine as well, it is not automatic.  How it could remember the old path is hard to guess, the registration code in the DLL ought to be borken.  Or you just registered it incorrectly by hacking the registry yourself.

Comment: There is no reference to the old path in either computers registries though... The regsvr32 is done automatically as part of the installer

Comment: The last step of an activex build is registering the binary with the Regsvr32.exe automatically. If you want to  move the binary to another location, just copy the dll file to the new location and register it again with Regsvr32.exe manually, the new location of the dll file will then be updated into the registry.   eg: `Regsvr32 c:\NewDllDirectory\MyDll.dll`

Answer (score 0):

What version of Windows? If it is 64bit are you sure you are looking in the right registry tree, there are separate ones for 32bit and 64bit. Being built with VC6 the DLL is registered in the 32bit section.